# /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file bin/genericMatching: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to compile my c++ program using makefile in ubuntu But there is an error which I can't understand. This is an error message I got.

```
 Parallel/ParallelSlave.o Parallel/IOHandler.o commons/File19794.o  -o    bin/genericMatching 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file bin/genericMatching: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:38: recipe for target 'bin/genericMatching' failed
```

This is codes inside my Makefile and there is no bin file/directory in my program folder :

```
# The compiler to use.
CC = mpiCC

# Directories for Includes and Common clases
IDIR =include
CDIR =commons/
JIANGDIR =MatcherJiang/
MCCDIR =MCC/
PDIR =Parallel/
BINDIR =bin/

# Compiler options -Weffc++
CFLAGS= -Wall -O2 -fopenmp -I$(IDIR) -I$(JIANGDIR) -I$(MCCDIR)

# Sources and Common clases sources
SOURCES= $(PDIR)genericMatching.cpp
SOURCESD= $(PDIR)DPDDFF.cpp
CSOURCES= $(CDIR)Fingerprint.cpp $(CDIR)Score.cpp $(JIANGDIR)FingerprintJiang.cpp  $(MCCDIR)MCC.cpp $(MCCDIR)Cylinder.cpp  $(CDIR)Functions.cpp $(CDIR)Minutia.cpp $(CDIR)GrahamScanConvexHull.cpp $(CDIR)Munkres.cpp $(PDIR)ParallelHandler.cpp $(PDIR)ParallelMaster.cpp $(PDIR)ParallelSlave.cpp $(PDIR)IOHandler.cpp $(CDIR)File19794.cpp


# Objects
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTSD=$(SOURCESD:.cpp=.o)
COBJECTS=$(CSOURCES:.cpp=.o)

# Name of the executable
EXECUTABLE=$(BINDIR)genericMatching
EXECUTABLED=$(BINDIR)DPDDFF

all: $(EXECUTABLE) $(EXECUTABLED)

.PHONY: doc

doc:
    doxygen Doxyfile

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) $(COBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(COBJECTS) $(OBJECTFILES) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(EXECUTABLED): $(OBJECTSD) $(COBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTSD) $(COBJECTS) $(OBJECTFILES) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECTSD) $(COBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE) $(EXECUTABLED)

mrproper: clean
    rm -r doc/latex doc/html
```

Comment: Does it work if you manually create the `bin` directory?

Answer (score 1):

When running this rule:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) $(COBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(COBJECTS) $(OBJECTFILES) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

it will implicitly run `ld` to create `$(EXECUTABLE)`, which is `bin/genericMatching`.  Because the bin directory does not exist, throws an error.   I would suggest adding:

```
$(EXECUTABLE) $(EXECUTABLED): | $(BIN)

$(BIN) :
    mkdir -p $@
```

to your makefile.   Make will generate the directory before building the executables.   Notice that the `|` makes it an [order-only](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) prerequisite, which means it will not rebuild  `$(EXECUTABLE)` or `$(EXECUTABLED)` if `$(BIN)` is newer than either target.